# Copy and paste multiple nested tables into a specific Word table cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've used WordEditor to create a table in an Outlook template and am planning to copy and paste multiple ranges from an excel workbook as a nested table in a specific cell of this table - the idea is that every time a new table is pasted into this cell, all existing tables are pushed away (I can figure out positioning of the tables at a later point).

I intend to use a bookmarks in order to paste the ranges, but am not familiar with the notation and am having a hard time finding any relevant documentation on the web

```
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim ws_sum, ws As Worksheet
Dim tblSess As Word.Table
......

......
With ws_sum
    wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="tab", Range:=tblSess.cell(2, 1).Range
    .Range(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(12, 7)).Copy
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("tab").Range.PasteAsNestedTable
    .Range(.Cells(24, 2), .Cells(31, 10)).Copy
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("tab").Range.PasteAsNestedTable
......
End With
```

The issue I'm having is that currently every time I paste a new nested table it completely removes the contents of the bookmarked cell. I tried specifying the first entry of the cell by replacing 'Range:=tblSess.cell(2, 1).Range' with 'Range:=tblSess.cell(2, 1).Range(0,0)' but this throws up an error upon running. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `Range(0,0)` doesn't work in Word  (anymore than `Cell(0,0)` would in Excel). `Range(1,1)` might do what you want, though. Personally, I use `Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart` to get to the beginning of a cell. But that would mean declaring and using an independent `Range` object (which wouldn't be such a bad thing...)

Comment: hi @CindyMeister so `Range.Collaspe wdCollapseStart` does indeed allow me to paste multiple tables in the cell, but it only works if I were to paste my following tables as `.Paste` rather than `.PasteSpecial` (the latter ends up pasting the secondary nested table within the first nested table, as a nested, nested table!). The issue with the former is then the table is no longer nested and becomes embedded to the main table... Is there a workaround to this you think?

Comment: Thanks for confirming - that gave me a place to start. I've posted an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's certainly more than one way to approach this. The key in any case is to

- Make sure there's an empty paragraph mark at the beginning of the cell. This provides a place to go back to for the next insertion so that it doesn't end up nested inside another pasted table.
- Use `Range` objects. I prefer two: one for the start of the cell, the other as the paste target.

The following code snippet, based on the code in the question, illustrates:

```
Dim rngCellStart As Word.Range, rngTarget As Word.Range

Set rngTarget = tblSess.Cell(2, 1).Range
rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Set rngCellStart = rngTarget.Duplicate

'put a paragraph mark before the table that is pasted
rngTarget.InsertBefore vbCr
'Move the target Range to leave out that paragraph
rngTarget.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1

'may no longer be needed... but could be used to mark
'the starting point of the cell as that is where it stays
'wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="tab", Range:=rngCellStart

.Range(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(12, 7)).Copy
rngTarget.PasteAsNestedTable

'Following paste actions for additional tables.
'Could be put in a separate procedure and called in a loop
rngCellStart.InsertBefore vbCr
Set rngTarget = rngCellStart.Duplicate
rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
.Range(.Cells(24, 2), .Cells(31, 10)).Copy
rngTarget.PasteAsNestedTable
```